# css linear-gradient background CPU high usage

Tags: css, background, css-animations, cpu-usage

Need to create linear gradient animation in body but it uses cpu a lot which causes fans to run loudly.

I found this solution
[animated linear gradient devouring CPU usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66104433/animated-linear-gradient-devouring-cpu-usage)

this trick lowers cpu usage down to 3-5% which is great. But when you resize the window it create a bug in the background.

Tried to create resize function because I guess when you resize the window the width property changes which causes the bug. But it didn't work out.

```
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/iclassici/pen/poPXRyp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In doing:

```
  body.classList.remove('bg');
  body.classList.add('bg');
```

actually nothing happens because the class is restored before the system has had a chance to recalculate/redraw stuff.

You'll need to remove the class as you have done, and then wait before reinstating it. Try setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame.

If you could make you code into a snippet which we can run in your question that would help us test things and give a fuller answer.

UPDATE: taking the code given in the codepen, this snippet makes a change to the resize function, removing a bganimation class, setting a short timeout and reinstating the class. This ensures that the system will reset whatever parameters it is giving the GPU.

Note: on my reasonably powerful laptop, Windows 10, the animation of the background is taking less than 2% CPU mostly and around 20% of the GPU.

```js
window.addEventListener("resize", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  body.classList.remove('bganimation');
  setTimeout(function() {
    body.classList.add('bganimation');
  }, 100);
}
```

```css
.bg {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.bg::before {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 600%;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #F17C58, #E94584, #24AADB, #27DBB1, #FFDC18, #FF3706);
  background-size: 100% 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
  background-position: left top;
}

.bganimation {
  animation: gradient 16s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes gradient {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-400vw);
    /* 5/6x100% */
  }
}
```

```html
<body class="bg bganimation">
</body>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your time. here is a codepen https://codepen.io/iclassici/pen/poPXRyp

Comment: I amseeing a black area on the right when I run the codepen - I imagine at the end of one animation cycle - is that intended?

Comment: I have added a snippet based on your codepen. I seemed to have to size the background image to get rid of seeing the white at the end.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to adjust your code to my needs. Thank you again!